# How can I create a stream out of a finite number of objects passed?

Tags: java, stream, set

I have a finite list of objects and when I call `getElements` I want to have a stream of all objects in that list.

```
private Set<T> object; 

public List(Set<T> objects) {
this.object = objects;
}
   
public Stream<T> getElements() {
        Stream<T> stream = object.stream();
        return stream;
}
```

So if I create a set and add 1 and 2 to it:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(1);
        set.add(2);

List<Integer> nums = new List<Integer>(set);

System.out.println(nums.getElements());
```

I am supposed to get 1,2 as output, but I get this instead:

```
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@7cc355be
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Try `System.out.println(nums.getElements().collect(Collectors.toList()));`. You can get `[1, 2]`.

Comment: I am looking for a way to implement that into my ``getElements``method, so that I don't have to make this change every time I call that method.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Getting a stream and printing the elements in a stream are two separate issues. Your method creates the stream without a problem. Simply passing in the stream to println() will just print the object reference. You either need to provide a print operation to the stream or simply pass in the original set/list to println().

Comment: This is for an assignment. My instructions say, that when I call ``nums.getElements()`` it has to show 1 and 2. And how would I provide a print operation in my stream?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the method in one of the following ways:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(1);
        set.add(2);
        MyList<Integer> nums = new MyList<Integer>(set);
        
        nums.printElements();
        
        System.out.println("\n" + nums.getAsList());
        
        System.out.println("Number of elements: " + nums.getElementStream().count());
    }

}

class MyList<T> {
    private Set<T> object; 

    public MyList(Set<T> objects) {
        this.object = objects;
    }
    
    //If you want to print all elements
    public void printElements() {
        object.stream().forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
    }
    
    //if you want them as a java.utli.List
    public List<T> getAsList(){
        return object.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    //if you want stream of the elements
    public Stream<T> getElementStream() {
            Stream<T> stream = object.stream();
            return stream;
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 
[1, 2]
Number of elements: 2
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not solve me problem. My instructions state, that what you implemented in ``printElements()`` needs to be returned when I call ``getElements()``.

Comment: @v_uztel You can't just print a Stream object; either the `getElements()` method needs to return a String instead, or extra steps need to be performed on the result of `getElements()` when it is called.